# Menú desplegable HTML - jQuery - CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css, menú

Deseo que al pasar el ratón por encima de un elemento de un menú me despliegue varias opciones. **¿Cómo se podría dar color blanco a los desplegables desde el jQuery a los -li-?**

**Deseo lo siguiente: Al pasar el ratón por encima de "infantil" me despliegue las 2 posibilidades existentes, y al quitar el ratón desaparezcan.**

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Ejemplo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="script/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse text-center" id="navegacion">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a href="natacion.html">NATACIÓN</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">ESCUELA</a></li>
                <li><a href="fitness.html">FITNESS</a></li>

                <li id="infantil"><a href="infantil.html">INFANTIL</a></li>
                    <ul id="desplegable">
                        <li>EXTRAESCOLARES</li>
                        <li>VACACIONES</li>
                    </ul>  
                </li>

                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#desplegable").css('display','none');    

                    $("infantil").mouseenter(function() {
                        $("#desplegable").show('slow');
                    });

                    $("infantil").mouseleave(function() {
                        $("#desplegable").hide('slow');

                    });
                });
                </script>

                <li><a href="cumpleaños.html">CUMPLEAÑOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="sala-bienestar.html">BIENESTAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="galeria.html">GALERÍA</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

El código que tengo para el **CSS** es el siguiente (no estoy seguro de que este CSS funcione correctamente):

```
ul #desplegable {
 background: darkcyan;
 width: 740px;
 float:left;
 padding: 5px;
}

ul #desplegable li {
 color: darkcyan;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0% 5%;
}

ul #desplegable li:hover{
 color: darkcyan;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: El error que me da es que al recargar la página se me muestran las 3 opciones y sólo quiero que sea al pasar el ratón encima.

Comment: A mi me funciona si quitas ese `</li>` que te sobra, y si referencias `infantil` con el `#` tal que : `$("#infantil").mouseenter` ...(ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/lois6b/7d9w0vxp/). Considero que es error tipografico. Tambien ten en cuenta el ancho del `div` ya que si pasas el raton por la derecha de la lista, sin  estar encima del texto, se despliega. Lo mejor será que pongas el evento sobre el `<a>` para que no te pase

Comment: Opino igual que @lois6b, es un error tipográfico. La pregunta está bien expuesta pero quizá se debería cerrar.